# Can a Canon 60D use sdxc cards?

Tags: canon-60d, sdxc

I have a 60D and I know sdhc cards work in it, I am unsure about sdxc though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**.  [According to Canon's website](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/slr_cameras/eos_60d?selectedName=Features&fileName=0901e024801e2fb2_feature9.html), the 60D has:

> Compatibility with SD/SDHC/SDXC memory
>   cards.

Comment: According to http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/E60D/E60DA6.HTM the 60D is not UHS-1 compliant. Therefore, though it will work with SDXC cards, the write speed is limited to about Class 10.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes** the Canon 60D is compatible with SDXC cards.  You will see it mentioned first on page 2 of the manual.  You can find a link to the manual on Canon's website [here](http://pdisp01.c-wss.com/gdl/WWUFORedirectTarget.do?id=MDMwMDAwNDAxOTAy&cmp=ABR&lang=EN).